# Resize <div> automatically based on text?

Tags: css, html, width, autosize

I've got the following JS Fiddle to demonstrate what I'm trying to accomplish:
http://jsfiddle.net/sVKU8/2/

1) I assume this first part is easy - Is there a way to update the parent `label` class to automatically have it's `width` set based on the total width of the two child `<div>`s so the border only wraps around the green and red `<div>`s? I thought setting `width: auto` was supposed to do that, but my CSS skills are apparently lacking.

2) What I'd like to accomplish next would be to remove the `width` attribute from my `label-text` class and have the width set (or grow automatically, if possible) whenever I apply text to that `<div>` via JavaScript without text wrapping (i.e. keeping the original height of the `label` class).

I wasn't sure if I needed to try to calculate the width based on the actual text, or if there is a way to just apply the text with a width setting that will allow it to grow.

Any input or suggestions would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 15, accepted):

[click here](http://jsfiddle.net/sVKU8/14/)
CSS alternative without additional JS using traditional `floating elements` approach

Comment: I'm going to go with this one, just because it didn't include any extra JS. I think this is the simpler approach. Thank you!

Comment: this only works if your text is just 1 row long. If I specify a max width it doesn't wrap to a new line

Comment: Nevermind - I commented out the "white-space: no-wrap" and it's now working for multiple lines!

Comment: Nevermind again, it doesn't work if you specify "text-align: left"... it leaves white space on the right :(

Answer (score 33):

Add this property to your css :

```
 .based-on-text{
   display: inline-block;
 }
```

This way, the div will act like a block but will have exactly the width it needs instead of taking the whole parent level width !

Comment: But this doesn't work in IE7 or earlier. I'm trying to make a fully compatible plugin, in case you are wondering. Is there a workaround for this?

Comment: Probably using the "float: left;" property of CSS, with a clearfix I guess. A little bit hacky but it works pretty well in most case. You have to apply the clearfix on the parent element
-> https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/clear-fix/

Answer (score 2):

This fiddle [(Click HERE)](http://jsfiddle.net/sVKU8/3/) shows using `inline-block` on the div `text-label` and a little JS to set the width on the outer box with the border.

This is the javascript. Pretty ugly. There's probably a better way:

```
$(".label").css("width", 
    parseFloat( $(".label-image").css("width")) 
    + parseFloat( $(".label-text").css("width"))
);
```